# extracting hyperlinks from rtf with python

Tags: python, csv, url, extract, rtf

I'm trying to extract hyperlinks from rtfs, with python. I have like a 1000 rtfs to go through so figured if this could ease my task. But my *code doesn't extract links to the articles, just the front page of that database*. Here's what I wrote:

```
import csv
import re

with open('text.rtf', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', line)
        print(urls)
        
with open ('some.csv','w') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    writer.writerows(urls)
```

And this is what's printed out:

[]

[]

[]

['https://database.com']

[]

[]

csv file is empty ...(And I want to write those urls into a csv file... Is it even possible?)

*I guess this needs to be modified: 'https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', line'*

I do not know how.

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex there are well-established regex for URL capturing use any one of them.

Comment: Thank you I'l look into that.

Comment: It doesn't help. Probably because I'm uncertain of how to use those. I get error codes all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in function `open` cannot alone decode RTF files. You'll need to install another package to handle that. There's another that can help with extracting urls from text as well. Not sure it's the most accurate url extractor solution, though.

```
pip install striprtf urlextract
```

Back in your main file you can try something like:

```
import csv
from striprtf import striprtf
from urlextract import URLExtract

with open( 'text.rtf', 'r') as rtf_file:
    file_text = striprtf.rtf_to_text( rtf_file.read() )

extractor = URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls(file_text)

with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    fieldnames = ['urls']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fw, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for link in urls:
        writer.writerow( {'urls': link} )
```

Hopefully this will get you what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one!

Comment: Gets complicated: It seems that striprtf.rtf_to_text( rtf_file.read()) is stripping away all the hyperlinks. :D I see if can get around it...

Comment: It worked, wow thank you! Except that I had to  change striprtf.rtf_to_text( rtf_file.read()) into rtf_file.read(). So it seem striprtf is no use in this.